# Unit test Distinct with keyselector and comparer

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

How would I go about unit testing this piece of LINQ code?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    return items.Distinct(new KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>(keySelector, comparer.Equals));
}
```

I do not know how to use the comparer at the end, what is the correct usage of this?

Edit: Sorry about being unclear;

What I would like to know:

1. What this code does.
2. How this code is used.
3. How I can unittest this piece of code.

KeyEqualityComparer:

```
class KeyEqualityComparer<T, TResult>: IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TResult> _KeySelector;
    private readonly Func<TResult, TResult, bool> _Predicate;

    public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, TResult> keySelector, Func<TResult, TResult, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (keySelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
        _KeySelector = keySelector;
        _Predicate = predicate ?? System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<TResult>.Default.Equals;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _Predicate(_KeySelector(x), _KeySelector(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        // Always return the same value to force the call to IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear whether your question is what the code does, how you should use it, or how you should unit test it...

Comment: You're right, I should've been clearer. I really want to know all of those you asked. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: Where does `KeyEqualityComparer` come from (and the rest of this code)? (It feels unlikely to work properly at the moment, for reasons which I'd rather only explain when I've seen the code.)

Comment: I added the code of the KeyEqualityComparer. This isn't my code and I am only a beginner at programming so excuse me for being such a newbie :). Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Ick, that's nasty - given the GetHashCode implementation, this is *not* good code to study, IMO. Are you in a position to change it?

Comment: I am in a position to change it, but would rather not given that I am only assigned to writing the unittest for the particular piece of code. And seeing as I am just a silly apprentice, I would rather not change it. What would be a better implementation if I may ask?

Comment: See the link to the MoreLINQ implementation in my answer :)

Comment: In fact this code is based on the MoreLINQ implementation, so I can imagine you see somewhat similar code. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why not just use MoreLINQ then? Why would anyone want to write a worse version?

Comment: It has been included in the companies Framework; why it has been partially included rather than included as a whole, I am afraid I don't know the answer, sorry!

Comment: I would *definitely* point out to your employers that this version is *very significantly* less efficient due to the flaw I explain in my answer.

Comment: I will once the guy responsible for this work gets in, thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is trying to do something similar to MoreLINQ's [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method, but not as well.

Fundamentally, the idea is that given a collection of items, you want to find a *distinct* set of items, but specifically testing for distinctness by comparing some notion of a key. As an example, you might have a `Person` type like this:

```
// TODO: Use C# 6 primary constructor and read-only autoprops :)
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hobby { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

with data like this:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name="Tom", Hobby="Minecraft", Profession = "Student" },
    new Person { Name="Robin", Hobby="Taunting", Profession = "Outlaw" },
    new Person { Name="Robin", Hobby="Angry Birds", Profession = "Student" },
};
```

Now we could get a distinct set of people by name (in which case we'd get Tom and one of the Robins) or by profession (in which case we'd get the outlaw and one of the students). We can addtionally specify an equality comparer to use when comparing keys - so that "TOM" and "Tom" might be considered equal, for example.

The `Distinct` method in LINQ already allows you to specify a custom equality comparer, so your `Distinct` method (which I wouldn't overload, by the way) just projects items to their keys and uses the given key equality comparer to compare those keys.

Unfortunately, the implementation given in the question is bad: an `IEqualityComparer<T>` has to provide two methods: one to compare two items for equality (which is being done correctly) and one to get a hash code (which is being done very badly - it's "valid" but horrendously inefficient). Basically this changes an O(N) algorithm into an O(N^2) algorithm by performing far more comparisons than are really needed.

In terms of unit tests, you could use pretty much the examples I've given above:

- Get a distinct set by name
- Get a distinct set by profession
- Get a distinct set by name with a case-insensitive equality comparer

You would want to find out requirements in terms of which item out of multiple equivalent ones should be returned - LINQ to Objects always returns the first it comes across, for example (although I don't *think* that's documented).

Or you could look at my [`DistinctByTest`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq.Test/DistinctByTest.cs) for the MoreLINQ tests :)